# Processing and storing emails in a database

Tags: java, email, thunderbird

I have lot of emails coming to my email client, Mozilla Thunderbird.

What I intend to do is write a Java program to process all those emails and store them in a database.

I need to know if this is possible? If yes, then it will be very helpful to get some tips on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use JavaMail (or more easily, any of many mail wrapping libraries, like [Commons Mail](http://commons.apache.org/email/), or whatever) to connect to your mail server. Grab the emails. Put them in a database using whatever DB methodology you prefer. It'd likely be far, far more useful if you indexed them in interesting ways using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html), though.

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thank you for the prompt response.
How to do this if I have configured my gmail account with thunderbird.

Comment: Your client isn't relevant, unless you're dead set on reading whatever format it keeps its mail in (mbox?)... Talk directly to the email server. Please read the documentation and examples of whatever mail library you're using. (I did screw up, though; commons-mail is for sending, for reading, you'd want JavaMail, Apache James, or even Apache Camel (Groovy example here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/04/use-apache-camel-plugin-in-grails.html)